# Firebase how to filter collection with a sub collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called "posts".
Posts has sub collection called "feedback".

when a user give feedback to a post his id and comment get added to feedback sub collection.

Now I want to find posts that user has not given a feedback.

Something like following sql query

```
select * from posts where userId not in (select userId from feedback)
```

Can someone provide advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support joins between collections or subqueries.  You won't be able to perform any queries that use data from more than one collection.

Also, querying for non-existence isn't supported by Firestore.  So, you won't be able to query for the absence of data in a field.  Firestore requires that all queries be able to use a highly performant index, which only tracks data present in documents.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What is the method we have to use to do this?

Comment: You would need to maintain some field (say `hasGivenFeedback`) on the main post object, and in order to keep it in sync, you can write a firebase cloud function to listen to any changes on the feedback collection, and write this value to the corresponding post.


If you're coming from a SQL background, this may be difficult to swallow at first, I had trouble myself, but this kind of duplication is normal for NoSQL databases.